# Is it possible to sequentially use one bluetooth keyboard with two Windows PCs?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, keyboard, bluetooth

I do have one bluetooth keyboard that I would like to sequentially use with two laptops. I can pair it to both laptops with the same key, but it still only works with the laptop I last paired it to. It seems to me that not only the key is important for pairing, but additional parameters that are unknown to me.

In detail, my use case is the following:

1. Use bluetooth keyboard with computer 1 (Windows XP).
2. Turn off computer 1.
3. Turn on computer 2.
4. Use bluetooth keyboard with computer 2 (Windows 7), without any manual setting up.

Can this be achieved in Windows?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the computers be switched off? If not, you could consider using a program like 'Synergy' which allows you to share your mouse and keyboard across 2 systems. It requires one system to always be switched on as the 'server' though.

Comment: @OliverG: Yes, that's the requirement. The idea is to have one workplace with a keyboard and a big screen and to exchange the computers. I know of Synergy and use it myself in other scenarios. In my scenario I may only have one computer available at a time. BTW, here's the same scenario for two Macs: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/sharing-a-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-sequentially-between-two-macs I don't want to use a hardware switch, but am looking for a pure "software" solution.

Comment: Get a Logitech device with the unifying receiver and buy a second receiver. It takes about 10 seconds to pair with another receiver: launch software, Initiate paring, power cycle device. I do it all the time between my laptop and desktop, you don't even have to get up as long as you have a receiver plugged into each device.

Comment: @Kyle: Thanks, that is basically the same as repairing the bluetooth keyboard every time I want to use it. I'm looking for a solution with my existing bluetooth setup without any manual intervention. Maybe this is just not possible... BTW, the keyboard is a Microsoft Bluetooth Keyboard 6000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether your keyboard supports simultaneous pairing with several devices or not.

Most keyboards support only one paired device. E.g. the moment you pair with your second computer, it forgets its first pairing, so when you want to use it again with your first computer, you need to pair it again.

Some keyboards support pairing with multiple devices, just like your bluetooth handsfree can pair with several phones, etc.

Read your keyboard's manual, if it doesn't say that it can pair with multiple devices, then most probably it cannot.